# How to re-write my Ruby method with Arel syntax?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, arel

I recently upgraded to Rails 5.2.X and I'm getting this deprecation warning now:

> DEPRECATION WARNING: Dangerous query method (method whose arguments
>   are used as raw SQL) called with non-attribute argument(s):
>   "LOWER(projects.name) desc". Non-attribute arguments will be
>   disallowed in Rails 6.0. This method should not be called with
>   user-provided values, such as request parameters or model attributes.
>   Known-safe values can be passed by wrapping them in Arel.sql().

I know that this deprecation message is being discussed [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/32995).

But still I'm struggling with the correct syntax.

This is my method:

```
def optimized_sort_column
  column_type == :string ? "LOWER(#{unique_sort_column})" : unique_sort_column
end
```

I've tried to change it to:

```
def optimized_sort_column
  column_type == :string ? Arel.sql("lower(#{unique_sort_column})") : unique_sort_column
end
```

But I'm still getting the same deprecation warning.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
.order(
  Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('lower', [unique_sort_column])
)
```

I think it's throwing the warning because the string interpolation inside the string you pass to Arel (probably isn't getting parsed that way).

I grabbed that off of [scuttle.io](http://scuttle.io), modifying the default query to order by `lower(author)` and tested locally with substituting variable names in place of author. It doesn't throw a warning.

Comment: `arel` actually naturally supports lower for an `Attribute` so this could be simplified to `arel_table[:unique_sort_column].lower` and will return the same as using the `NamedFunction` class directly